# How do I launch the same script automatically for hundreds of users?

Tags: shell

I have hundreds of users on my server who need to launch the same script (https://sourceforge.net/projects/igcc/) automatically when they are logged in. Should I put a copy of the script in their home directory for each of them?

Comment: So, is that for *all* users, or *all* users except a select few, or a list of hundreds of specific users?

Comment: The one thing that is for certain is that you don't need to copy the file to each home directory.

Comment: @muru Thanks for asking. The script is not for all users, though the group of users who need the script have the same groupid.

Comment: What is the OS? A simple conditional statement to execute the script based on the groupname or GID via one of the shell init scripts will be sufficeent.

Comment: @NasirRiley Thanks for asking. Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: um, is the "script" you want to launch by any chance actually the *shell* that these users should get?

Comment: by the way, seeing that igcc hasn't been touched in five years, with multiple C++ standards coming out since that: definitely not the C/C++ REPL you want to use, when you can have [cling](https://github.com/root-project/cling) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the script in the users' home directories doesn't help, you'll still need some way to run it.

Put the script (or a link to it) in some sensible directory, and then have one of the global shell startup files run the tool if the user is in the given group. To run at login, you could use `/etc/profile` or a file in `/etc/profile.d/` on most systems. Then you can test the group membership with something like this:

```
if id | grep -qwF specialgroup; then
    /path/to/specialtool
fi
```

The `id` on Linux prints something like `...groups=1000(blah),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy)...` and `grep -w` looks for full-word matches. This should work as long as your group names only contain "word characters" in the programming language sense, i.e. `a-zA-Z0-9_`. If they don't then, well, you'll have to do something different.

Instead of `id` you could use `groups`, or whatever your system has if it's not a GNU/Linux system.

(Of course, you could also put the script somewhere in `PATH` so you wouldn't need to embed the full path in the login script.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Does "sensible directory" mean somewhere like `/usr/local/` in this case?

Comment: @JJJohn, `/usr/local/bin` maybe. Or put it actually somewhere else and pull a symlink from there. `/usr/local/bin` might be in the `PATH` by default, so it has that, but I can see sense collecting tools like that somewhere else. (Maybe with revision control. Or well, if you go the long way, make a git repo and add an installer script that copies them to `/usr/local/bin`)

Answer (score 0):

(can't comment, not enough rep...)

From the comments exchange I'd say that you need to set your script as owned by this group of users (and update the ugo permissions accordingly), then append a line in their .bashrc (or any equivalent file based on the OS) to launch said script.

It seems like a great tool by the way.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that the idea you mention seems good enough for a full-fledged answer, but you would need to complete it to fill in the missing steps (however, it seems @ilkkachu already did so in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673201/377345) in the meantime).

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to run for these users seems to be a shell, not a script that you want to run before their shell (e.g., bash) would become interactive.

In that case: wrong construction site! You just set their shell to that, using the `chsh` command. see `man chsh` for details.

---

Remark, disregard if inappropriate because you're bound to your C++ interpreter for some reason:

By the way, seeing that igcc hasn't been touched in five years, with multiple C++ standards coming out since that: definitely not the C/C++ REPL you want to use, when you can have [cling](https://github.com/root-project/cling) instead.